# Quit Master's for a PHD?

Tags: phd, masters

Looking for advice: Anyone ever hear of people who quit their masters to do a PhD? My colleague in our masters (math) will be applying for PhDs this fall as with the usual cycle. However, he entered the masters on a spring semester, hence he is one semester behind with respect to the usual requirements. If he was to be admitted, it is highly unlikely that he would be able to finish the masters on time.

In particular

(a): would it be best to defer PhD matriculation? The clear advantage here is that of safety - in case one isn't suited for a PhD, one at least has a masters to fall back on.

(b): would it be best to accept? This seems to be the better option, except it seems like it would mean burning bridges with faculty at the masters.

Looking for pros and cons.

Also: a friend is interested in trying their hand at academia, but would like to be viable for industry. Don't we all?

Comment: Hi @Papuseme The answer to your question is "yes I do know people who have done that", but I suspect you might really be looking for the answer to a different question than that. Would you like to edit and clarify?

Comment: *Anyone ever hear of people who quit their masters to do a phd?* --- I did this during my 4th (and final) graduate school attendance, as described in this [10 April 2007 sci.math post](https://groups.google.com/g/sci.math/c/zP3J23lq1I0/m/9qGYFqMr08oJ). However, it seems you're assuming (but you don't actually say this) that the person doesn't have a masters to begin with, unlike my situation.

Comment: Is this for the US or another country?

Comment: Are you certain he won't be finished? Presumably he entered last spring, that means he will have completed this year and still have next year plus summer to finish. That seems like enough time even even for programs that typically last 3 years...

Comment: @DaveLRenfro yes, no masters yet.  this is for the US and almost for sure they won't be finished by then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the US there is seldom a requirement that one hold a masters before starting a doctorate (or ever, actually). Unless the major field or the institution is exceptional, the person could simply drop out of the masters and begin the doctoral study.

Most US doctoral applicants hold only a bachelors degree and the doctoral program is designed to accommodate that smoothly. A masters may or may not shorten doctoral study depending on the match between what was studied and what needs to be studied for the usual (not universal) comprehensive/qualifying exams and research preparation.

If a masters is required that will be made quite clear in the application process.

The candidate need to give an honest application, of course, not implying that they will have a masters before starting. They will be evaluated fairly.

And, changing programs more generally is pretty common in US. I don't see any downside for your friend. If they can get admitted they can start and should probably just drop out of the masters program if they do.